# Can this code utilizing promises be written more succinctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I've written the following code to get all `.txt` files in a directory and read+delete them, repeating every 15 seconds.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Q = require("q");
var dir = "stuff";

var analyseFile = function(fileData, callback) { ... }; // Not important.

var deleteFile = function(filePath, callback) { ... }; // Not important.

var processStuffDir = function() {
  Q.nfcall(fs.readdir, dir).then(function(files) {
    return Q.all(
      files.filter(function(file) { 
        return path.extname(file) === ".txt";
      }).map(function(file) {
        var filePath = path.join(dir, file);
        return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, filePath).then(function(data) {
          return Q.nfcall(analyseFile, data.toString());
        }).then(function() {
          return Q.nfcall(deleteFile, filePath);
        });
      })
    );
  }).then(function() {
    setTimeout(processStuffDir, 15000);
  });
};

processStuffDir();
```

This works, but it's my first foray into using promises. So my question is, can this be re-written in a simpler/more succinct manner? More chaining of promises would be nice, if possible.

Comment: Looks fine, apart from the fact that any self-written functions (`analyseFile`, `deleteFile`) should return promises right away instead of taking callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

This is Bluebird, but it's very similar to Q in syntax. Note the automatic promisification and utility methods:

```
var Promise= require("bluebird");
var fs = Promise.promisify(require("fs"));
var path = require("path");

var dir = "stuff";

var analyseFile = function(fileData, callback) { ... }; // Not important.

var deleteFile = function(filePath, callback) { ... }; // Not important.

var fileOps = {
    analyse: Promise.promisify(analyseFile), // do this _once_
    delete: Promise.promisify(deleteFile)
}

var processStuffDir = function() {
  return fs.readDirAsync(dir).filter(function(files) {
        return path.extname(file) === ".txt";
  }).map(function(file){
        return path.join(dir, file)
  }).map(function(file) {
      return fs.readFileAsync(file).then(function(data) {
          return fileOps.analyse(data.toString());
      }).then(function() {
          return fileOps.delete(filePath);
      });
  }).delay(15000).then(processStuffDir);
};

processStuffDir();
```